# How can I replace string in for loop using the index

Tags: python

```
def functionsdiv(S):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(S)):
        for k in range(9):
            S.replace(S[i], str(k))
            print(S)
            numbers = int(S)
            if numbers %3 == 0:
                count+=1
        return count
```

I did this but the string won't be replaced in any iteration.

An example input would be `"23"`.

I try to replace number with every number possible and look whether how many number that can be mod by 3 ==0

Comment: Not sure i follow on what you are trying to do, but the replace method doesn't change the string itself since a string is immutable. Instead it returns a new string `S = S.replace(S[i], str(k))` would update S

Answer (score 0):

The replace operation is not executed inplace (meaning that it returns the edited string, but does not change the original). Use another variable. Also, return outside of the loop.

```
def functionsdiv(S):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(S)):
        for k in range(9):
            S_temp = S.replace(S[i], str(k))
            print(S_temp)
            numbers = int(S_temp)
            if (numbers %3) == 0:
                count+=1
    
    return count
```

output:

```
functionsdiv('23')
# 03
# 13
# 23
# 33
# 43
# 53
# 63
# 73
# 83
# 20
# 21
# 22
# 23
# 24
# 25
# 26
# 27
# 28
# 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the string after doing the replace to another variable as string is immutable and also you need to do the return statement after the second for loop - proper indentation

```py
def functionsdiv(S):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(S)):
        for k in range(9):
            temp = S.replace(S[i], str(k))
            print(temp)
            numbers = int(temp)
            if numbers %3 == 0:
                count+=1
    return count
        
S = "23"
print(functionsdiv(S))
```

Output

```
03
13
23
33
43
53
63
73
83
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
6
```

Comment: The first assignment of the temp variable (`temp = S`) is not necessary, I removed it for you. ;)

Comment: Yeah, its true.